# Problem with RVM use

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, zsh

I am having trouble with using rvm use in zsh. Whenever I do `rvm use 1.9.2` or other ruby version, it gives confirmation as `Using /home/kxhitiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290`
But when I do `rvm list` ruby 1.9.2 is not selected. This works fine in bash. That means I can go to bash and select ruby version I need, and I can come back to zsh to use it.

So that means if I have to change ruby from list of rubies I have installed, I have to go to bash to select it and once selected in bash, I can see it selected in zsh as well.

Any solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you call $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm somewhere in your .zshrc? Also, see this: http://beginrescueend.com/integration/zsh/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did fixed it by adding following line at the end of my ~/.zshrc file
`[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*`

Cheers!